# Swift : change style of a button when pressed and reset other buttons

Tags: swift, button

So I've got these buttons (3 stacks of 6, so 18), and what I want to achieve is when I press one of these buttons :

- border color & text color changes
- the other buttons are reset to their normal styling

But I don't want to disable the others via a "isEnabled" trick (I've only found solutions here involving isEnabled), I still want them to be enabled, I just want them not to be "highlighted" with my custom styling when one is pressed.

for the first part which is just the styling I did this inside the IBAction :

```
@IBAction func preset1Pressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    preset1.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.4095217415, green: 0.6107917746, blue: 0.2774988226, alpha: 1)
    preset1.layer.borderWidth = 0.42
    preset1.setTitleColor(#colorLiteral(red: 0.4095217415, green: 0.6107917746, blue: 0.2774988226, alpha: 1), for: .normal)
}
```

This small portion was just for 1 button, but I guess if I have 18 of them I should make a class or a struct rather than copy this inside each IBAction ?? Or a func ?

Then for the 2nd part I'm not sure about how to do it, reversing to the original properties (set in the Attributes Inspector) of the other buttons when one is pressed.
Intuitively I'm sure it's a combination of an array of all the 18 buttons inside a function that would loop through all the array, and maybe make a bool on each button to check if they are pressed or not, but I really don't know how the syntax would be...

Worth noting also that if I press twice on the same button I don't want it to reverse to its original properties but to keep the "pressed" styling.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what suggested Dilan did not completely solve it on its own, though I experimented with it and it actually helped me solve it, apart I did these modifications :

I created my Array of buttons (called presetsArray) and tagged them.
Then I created a function to be called in all IBActions, but as sender.tag wouldn't work here's how I worked out the function :

```
func styleButtons(tag: Int) {
        let tag = tag
        presetsArray.forEach{ (button) in
            if button.tag == tag {
                button.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.4095217415, green: 0.6107917746, blue: 0.2774988226, alpha: 1)
                button.layer.borderWidth = 0.42
                button.setTitleColor(#colorLiteral(red: 0.4095217415, green: 0.6107917746, blue: 0.2774988226, alpha: 1), for: .normal)
                view.layoutIfNeeded()
            } else {
                button.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
                button.setTitleColor(#colorLiteral(red: 0.4978774786, green: 0.5020093918, blue: 0.5019439459, alpha: 1), for: .normal)
            }
        }
    }
```

Then in each IBAction for preset X I would call it like this :

```
styleButtons(tag: presetX.tag)
```

In the else section of my function as view.layoutIfNeeded() wouldn't reverse back to my original styling I just went for the color picker and picked my original styling, not the most legit way to do this I feel but it works !

Thanks a lot Dilan for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Define UIButton array and add buttons when you add it to stack.set index as button tag (0-17)

```
fileprivate var btnArray:[UIButton] = []

btn0.tag = 0
btnArray.appent(btn0)
```

Then you can change style in button click function like this

```
    @IBAction func preset1Pressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

       btnArray.forEach { (button) in
            if button.tag == sender.tag {
                preset1.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.4095217415, green: 0.6107917746, blue: 0.2774988226, alpha: 1)
                preset1.layer.borderWidth = 0.42
                preset1.setTitleColor(#colorLiteral(red: 0.4095217415, green: 0.6107917746, blue: 0.2774988226, alpha: 1), for: .normal)
                view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }else{
                //add default style
                view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
        }
    }
```

Don't frogot to add view.layoutIfNeeded() after this

Comment: Hey Dilan, thanks for your answer but it doesn't work... It just does the same thing as what I did before, meaning styling the button that I click but if I click on 3 buttons they're still all styled with my custom stuff, the others are not being reversed to their original properties even with view.layoutIdNeeded(). Plus, if I have to do this long portion of code inside every IBAction of each button, wouldn't that be a waste of lines of code ? isn't there a way to make it a funcion that I call in each IBAction rather than having this long portion of code every time ? thanks